# How to get list of Direct Directories named something-* using C# in D:\myfolder\

Tags: c#, winforms, directory

How to get list of Direct Directories named something-***** using C# in **D:\myfolder**

I tried

```
        String root = @"E:\something-*";
        var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(root);
```

but it is giving error infact, the listing of E:\ also results in **null** as value in variable **directories**.

[image]

I also tried looking for possible solutions on stackoverflow and other forums but did not get any appropriate answer to my query.

Comment: You could try something like this:  var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(root).Where(d => d.Name.Contains("something-")); Oh, and make your root equal "D:\myfolder\".

Comment: D.Name is giving error

Comment: I added an answer that should work for you. see below

Answer (score 0):

You need the overload of GetDirectories that takes a search pattern and prepare the correct pattern to search for

```
String root = @"E:\something-*";
string parent = Path.GetDirectoryName(root);

// A little trick, here GetFilename will return "something-*"
string search = Path.GetFileName(root);
var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(parent, search);
```

There is also a third overload that allows you to search the pattern recursively under the parent folder

```
    var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(parent, search, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

The problem you are experiencing is caused by the presence of system directories like the System Volume Information on which you don't have permission to read its content. MSDN has an example how to overcome this situation and could be adapted to your requirements with some minor changes like the one here below

```
// Call the WalkDirectoryTree with the parameters below
// Notice that I have removed the * in the search pattern    
var dirs = WalkDirectoryTree(@"E:\", @"something-");

List<string> WalkDirectoryTree(string root, string search)
{
    try
    {
        var  files = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.*");
    }
    // This is thrown if even one of the files requires permissions greater
    // than the application provides.
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
        // This code just writes out the message and continues to recurse.
        // You may decide to do something different here. For example, you
        // can try to elevate your privileges and access the file again.
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return new List<string>();
    }

    catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return new List<string>();
    }

    // Now find all the subdirectories under this directory.
    List<string> subDirs = new List<string>();
    List<string> curDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(root).ToList();
    foreach (string s in curDirs)
    {
        if(s.StartsWith(search))
            subDirs.Add(s);
        var result = WalkDirectoryTree(s, search);
        subDirs.AddRange(result);
    }
    return subDirs;
}
```

Comment: Still the dirs variable contains **null** https://i.imgur.com/GjmmxG1.png

Comment: This means that you don't have any directory that starts with the word "something-" in your folders directly under the E:\ root (or you don't have permissions to see these folders under the user account that runs your program)

Comment: Please show the whole folder tree starting from the root E:\

Comment: Also check if you have any kind of try/catch around that code that hides any permission exception while you are looking for these folders. By the way, from the images posted it seems that you haven't still executed the call to GetDirectories.

Comment: I have also tried on D:, but still null value is coming. https://i.imgur.com/hlJpYrg.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176524/discussion-between-steve-and-thompson).

Comment: answer updated with recursive call to avoid permission problems

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that will compile an array of DirectoryInfo objects (directories) that match the SearchPatn that exists in the Path.
 So, if Path equals "D:\myfolders\" and SearchPatn equals "something-*", You'll get results like: something-abc, something-xyz as folders that you can manipulate.

Caution with the searchOption: AllDirectories will search through all the folders below your path and return anything it finds. If you only want folders from your root, use the TopDirectoryOnly searchOption.

```
    // this returns an array of folders based on the SearchPatn (i.e., the folders you're looking for)
    private DirectoryInfo[] getSourceFolders(string Path, string SearchPatn)
    {
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] f = new DirectoryInfo(Path).GetDirectories(SearchPatn, searchOption: SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        return f;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why none of the solutions are working for me. every solution is giving null as response. https://i.imgur.com/DQ6p8zJ.png

Comment: I tend to agree with @Steve. Have you done a manual check to make sure that the folders exist and are within the scope of you app?

Comment: @Thompson, make sure that the path separator char is between your path and your search pattern when it processes. Step through your debug if you have to, or add the object to your watches.